# Loop over a JSON in bash script

Tags: json, bash, api, curl, jq

The target is to create environment variables from data retrieved from an API in JSON format.

Example:

```
ValueA=pass1
ValueB=pass2
...
```

```
result=$(curl -l -k -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer ${token}" "$PasswordServerURL/api/v6/rest/folders/$IdFolder" | jq -r '.Credentials')
```

By running the command I get the following output for **$result**:

```
[
   {
      "CustomUserFields":{
         
      },
      "CustomApplicationFields":{
         
      },
      "Attachments":[
         
      ],
      "Tags":[
         
      ],
      "HasModifyEntriesAccess":true,
      "HasViewEntryContentsAccess":true,
      "HasViewEntryPasswordAccess":true,
      "CommentPrompts":{
         "AskForCommentOnViewPassword":false,
         "AskForCommentOnViewOffline":false,
         "AskForCommentOnModifyEntries":false,
         "AskForCommentOnMoveEntries":false,
         "AskForCommentOnMoveFolders":false,
         "AskForCommentOnModifyFolders":false
      },
      "Id":"34307337-6b90-4b6f-bc1d-3dba50fa9cbd",
      "Name":"valueA",
      "Username":"valueA",
      "Password":null,
      "Url":"",
      "Notes":"",
      "GroupId":"cd52d662-0771-4eb6-9309-d12aff60b6bb",
      "Created":"2021-06-16T00:07:44+02:00",
      "Modified":"2021-06-16T18:52:00+02:00",
      "Expires":null
   },
   {
      "CustomUserFields":{
         
      },
      "CustomApplicationFields":{
         
      },
      "Attachments":[
         
      ],
      "Tags":[
         
      ],
      "HasModifyEntriesAccess":true,
      "HasViewEntryContentsAccess":true,
      "HasViewEntryPasswordAccess":true,
      "CommentPrompts":{
         "AskForCommentOnViewPassword":false,
         "AskForCommentOnViewOffline":false,
         "AskForCommentOnModifyEntries":false,
         "AskForCommentOnMoveEntries":false,
         "AskForCommentOnMoveFolders":false,
         "AskForCommentOnModifyFolders":false
      },
      "Id":"c92729e3-1325-4725-ae8e-baba4a0d31b5",
      "Name":"ValueB",
      "Username":"ValueB",
      "Password":null,
      "Url":"",
      "Notes":"",
      "GroupId":"cd52d662-0771-4eb6-9309-d12aff60b6bb",
      "Created":"2021-06-16T00:08:05+02:00",
      "Modified":"2021-06-16T18:51:48+02:00",
      "Expires":null
   }
]
```

To get the password, I get the id of **$result** and I use a loop for with another **curl** :

```
ListeId=$(echo "${result}" | jq -r ".[] | .Id")
for CredId in $ListeId
do
secret=$(curl -l -k -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: ${token}" "$PasswordServerURL/api/v6/rest/credential/$CredId/password")
done
```

I get "pass1" and "pass2"

How to match each username (Value A, ValueB ...) to its password ?
The second question is how to export them as an environment variable in a bash script?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what you mean by "exporting them as an environment variable", but you could start by looking at the following variation of your code, though I would not actually recommend `export "$Username=$secret"`:

```
while read -r CredId Username
do
    secret=$(curl -l -k -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: ${token}" "$PasswordServerURL/api/v6/rest/credential/$CredId/password")
    export "$Username=$secret"
    echo "Username:secret=$Username:$secret"
done < <(jq -r '.[] | "\(.Id) \(.Username)"' < so-loop-over-json.json)
```

The above of course depends on the assumption that "Credid" is a single token. If there is any doubt about that, it's easy enough to adapt the foregoing accordingly.

With thanks to @GlennJackman.

Comment: Nice. The username/password pairs can be stashed in an associative array, if needed. Better to quote `export "$Username=$secret"` -- who knows what characters will be in the password.

Comment: Alternate `jq` output: `jq -r '.[] | [.Id, .Username] | @tsv'`

Comment: The username, I have to get it from the JSON of **$result**. If I do an "export valueA=pass1" in the bash script, I will not have the environment variable

Comment: If you look more carefully at the given solution, you'll see the Username comes from what you have called $result.

Comment: By the way, it would probably help if you explained in more detail what you mean by "exporting them as an environment variable".  Do you mean as an array? Two arrays? ...???

Comment: It's good, thank you :), I mean in my environment variable Linux OS